# Object pool vs Object container

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

What is the difference between object container (such as tomcat / spring container) vs object pool? At a high level both manages the object life cycle. Only difference I note is that multiple objects are loaned from pool of the similar type while the container creates objects of different types which may be used in the application. Interested to know if there is something more to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object Pool:

It is a collection of Objects from which we can get an available Object for our operational purposes.

You can think of Object pool as a deck of cards, from which you can draw a card.

Object Container:

It is a specialized environment for an object to execute. The container process the object with the pre defined life cyle methods.

You can think of Object container as Game Table, in which we're playing with the cards drawn from deck.

Comment: Thanks..Liked the "specialized environment" concept..Not able to upvote as I don't have enough reputation..:(

Comment: But you can make accepted :) Since you've created the question @SRaj

Answer (score 0):

The pool reduces the number of objects created.  If you need an object, ask the pool for one.  If it has one to give you, it does.  Otherwise it creates a new one.  When you're done with the object, return it to the pool for later reuse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am interested in the difference between pool and container..

Comment: A container like Tomcat is an object that can receive and process requests from a client.    When a request is made to Tomcat, it delegates the request to the appropriate servlet, which generates the webpage.